# The documentation indexer error message gives an incorrect link

Tags: ros, documentation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If my package is not found in rosdistro//doc.yaml, the wiki page displays a message like this:

Cannot load information on name: razor_imu_9dof, distro: indigo, which means that it is not yet in our index. Please see this page for information on how to submit your repository to our index.

The link to "this page" points to http://wiki.ros.org/Get%20Involved#Indexing_Your_.2A-ros-pkg_Repository_for_Documentation_Generation

That tag no longer exists, and in fact, the error message should point to this tutorial:
http://wiki.ros.org/rosdistro/Tutorials/Indexing%20Your%20ROS%20Repository%20for%20Documentation%20Generation

The link is doubtless deep in some build file, but I don't know how to submit a bug report to get it fixed because I don't know what package it's in. Can someone help please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196557/the-documentation-indexer-error-message-gives-an-incorrect-link/) by [PaulBouchier](https://answers.ros.org/users/2700/paulbouchier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 300 on 2014-11-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The code which generates that error message is here: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/roswiki/blob/9734c594a5fee3d0bc4cd942ea64e9e6a9bbd4b3/macro/macroutils.py#L23

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-02-26**:
PR: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/roswiki/pull/120